# how to get activity object use jni？

Tags: java, android, c++

A `*.so` file ,I want to get the installed packages list ,But I don't have  context pointer  `thiz point` But only `env pointer`, What should I do?

That means I only have  the `jnienv pointer`, but I want to get the installed apks list in system... How can I do that?

```
Java_com_kings0527_JNIGetCert_JNIGetCert_stringFromJNI( JNIEnv* env,
                                                  jobject thiz )
{
jclass activityClass = (*env)->FindClass(env, "android/app/Activity");
jmethodID getPackageManagerMid = (*env)->GetMethodID(env, activityClass, "getPackageManager", "()Landroid/content/pm/PackageManager;");
jobject packageManagerObject = (*env)->CallObjectMethod(env, thiz, getPackageManagerMid);
```

I need the Activity context.（jobject thiz）

Who can share your idea?  Thank you very much!

Comment: everybody hhhhhhhhhhere????

Comment: anybody here?   help !

Comment: I'm having the same problem, did you managed to solve this ? Thanks,/C.

Comment: Did you figured out how to do this?
Regards,